# Error: Message content must be a non-empty string. || if (typeof data !== 'string') throw new error(errorMessage);

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hi i have problem with using guild on my discord bot. Whenever i want to return the amount of the users on my server i recive this error

> if (typeof data !== 'string') throw new error(errorMessage);

> RangeError [MESSAGE_CONTENT_TYPE]: Message content must be a non-empty string.

```
if (cmd === `name`) { //This is working when used on discord text-channel
        msg.reply(msg.guild.name)
    }
    if (cmd === `users`) {  //This is not working when used on discord text-channel
        msg.reply(msg.guild.memberCount)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `memberCount` property returns a number which you are trying to send in a channel. The problem is that sending a number is not allowed. Your message content must **always** be a string.

You can solve this problem by using the `String` function to send a number. Your command will look like this:

```js
if(cmd === `users`){
    msg.reply(String(msg.guild.memberCount));
}
```

Comment: Using string concatenation also works: ``${msg.guild.memberCount}``